# How can we prove that this integral is zero?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, expected-value

In solving another problem, I came across this observation that apparently:

$ \int_\mathbb{R} (\tanh(cx+c^2) -\tanh^2(cx+c^2)  ) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = 0$.

It seems true (I have checked with numerical methods only) for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know if there is a way to prove it. In particular, as seen in the graph below, the function $(\tanh(cx+c^2) -\tanh^2(cx+c^2)  )$ is not odd (or does not seem to have any nice symmetry features that help simplify the integral.), as seen in the graph below for $c=1$.

One can write this integral as $\sqrt{2\pi} \mathbb{E}[\tanh(cX+c^2) -\tanh^2(cX+c^2)]$ where $X$ is standard-normally distributed.

Any idea is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The area under that curve looks negative to me.

Comment: @JohnDouma the question is not about the area under that curve, but the product of that with a normal pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\cosh u-\sinh u=e^{-u}$ so $$(\cosh (c^2+cx)-\sinh (c^2+cx))e^{-x^2/2}=e^{-(c+x)^2/2}e^{-c^2/2}$$

Hence $$\int_\mathbb{R} (\tanh(cx+c^2) -\tanh^2(cx+c^2)) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=$$ $$=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{-(c+x)^2/2}e^{-c^2/2}\sinh(cx+c^2)dx}{\cosh^2(cx+c^2)}$$

But now putting $c+x=y$ one gets that the integral above is:

$$e^{-c^2/2}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{-y^2/2}\sinh(cy)dy}{\cosh^2(cy)}=0$$ since the integrand is odd!